# CakePHP perde SESSION depois de um redirecionamento

Tags: php, cakephp, session

Estou fazendo uma integração com o Facebook Login. Quando o usuário clica para se logar usando o Facebook e aceita a aplicação ele é redirecionado para um método que cria uma SESSION e redireciona.

O problema é que os dados desta SESSION se perdem quando tento recuperá-los no outro link.

Eu criei um método de teste onde ele simplesmente grava uma *session* e em outro *controller* eu recupero essa SESSION de forma esperada.

Por este motivo eu comecei a desconfiar que o problema pode ser no tipo de dados que vem junto com a URL que o Facebook redireciona para minha aplicação.

Em todos os locais de minha aplicação estou usando o `$components = array('Session')`.

Como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Como é bom explanar sua pergunta. Acabei tendo uma ideia assim que fiz a pergunta. O SDK do Facebook tenta criar um session_id. Como na estrutura do CakePHP ele provavelmente é chamado primeiro, acabava sobrescrevendo a SESSION do CakePHP.

Acabei achando esta solução https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cake-php/2taXmyei4LM/-x0lrx2hi20J

No arquivo do SDK do Facebook simplesmente coloquei uma chamada para usar os recursos de SESSION do CakePHP antes do include.

No SDK PHP do Facebook, mas precisamente no arquivo facebook.php eu incluí a chamada CakeSession::read() antes do require_once:

```
CakeSession::read();

require_once "base_facebook.php";
```

Problema resolvido.